# Can I _boot_ using a Macbook Superdrive DVD with a Windows PC?

Tags: windows-8, usb, dell-latitude

Specifically a Dell Latitude. I am not sure if there is something special I could do to make it work. It does not work for me to use it as a boot device currently, although a no-name DVD drive will.

I have seen things like this: 
[Hacker Fixes MacBook Air SuperDrive to Work With Any Computer](http://www.wired.com/2008/06/hacker-fixes-ma/) from 2008 where the person replaced a part. Is that still a problem with a 2015 Superdrive?

I have also seen that it is possible with drivers to use a Mac Superdrive on a PC. [Does Apple MacBook Air Superdrive to work on any PC?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-hardware/does-apple-macbook-air-superdrive-to-work-on-any/1fd104bc-ff63-4915-affe-1c97bcbc2450)

On the other hand there are stories like this: Apple USB Superdrive – A cautionary tale - at www.niftytechblog.com/2013/01/15/apple-usb-superdrive-a-cautionary-tale/

Answer (score 0):

It is likely missing the required drivers and Windows can't recognize it without them. The instructions below can probably be modified to work with a native windows installation as well.

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1012885